# Sending a signal to a parent process

Tags: shell, kill, background-process, signals

I am trying to implement a timeout for a big script which calls a lot of external process.

I start a separate process as a watchdog that checks every second if the timeout is reached

```
(

  PARENT_PID=$$

  ((t = 2 ))
  while ((t > 0)); do
    sleep 1
    ((t -= 1))
  done

  kill -s ALRM ${PARENT_PID} 2> /dev/null

) &
```

And then I trap the `ALRM` signal in the main script

```
trap critical ALRM
```

and finally in the critical function I print out some text and exit the program cleanly

Now the problem

- if the timeout occurs while $PARENT_PID is running everything works as expected
- if the timeout occurs while a child process is running (e.g., I call openssl and openssl is running) nothing happens. If I terminate the running child process (e.g. by pressing <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) the parent process trap is activated and everything continues as expected

How can I fix the problem? So that the trap in the parent process is called and I can terminate the whole?

**Update**

If the watchdog kills with `-KILL` the parent process, the process with all the child processed are terminated as expected

The problem is that I would like to intercept the timeout and generate some output. For this reason I use the ALRM signal.

The `KILL` signal cannot be ignored while the `ALRM` one can.

My idea at the moment is the following:

- the parent process has a trap for the alarm
- the child process ignores the alarm signal
- when the signal is sent to the parent the child process is running and the parent is in the background
- my process is waken up when the child is terminated

If this is correct my idea will never work.

To make it work I should for each child process

- start it in the background
- wait for it and continue

So that the parent process will be able to trap the signal

Am I correct?

**Update 2**

A reduced example

```
critical() {
    printf "whathever\n"
    WATCHDOG_PID=$!
    kill -TERM $WATCHDOG_PID
}

(

    PARENT_PID=$$

    ((t = "${TIMEOUT}" ))
    while ((t > 0)); do
        sleep 1
        ((t -= 1))
    done

    kill -s ALRM ${PARENT_PID} 2> /dev/null

) &

trap critical ALRM

# an example of a long running command
(echo 'Q' | openssl s_client -connect corti.li:imap -servername corti.li -verify 6 ) &
wait

WATCHDOG_PID=$!
kill -TERM $WATCHDOG_PID
```

If the ALRM signal is sent while `openssl` is running nothing happens. Even if the `openssl` is in the background the trap is never called

Comment: Why not just wrap the parent process with `timeout(1)` ?

Comment: I want the solution to be portable and timeout is not installed by default on non-GNU systems (e.g., macOS, BSD, ...)

Comment: Is the use of "wait" not a consideration?

Comment: Could you please elaborate: how? (sorry but just "how?" was too short for a comment)

Comment: I obviously don't know your use case scenario fully enough but you could spawn the commands from the master script with wait and a timeout, The master script will spawn the child processes, wait for the timeout and then continue. "Wait" is a bash implementation and so if you are using another shell it may not be any good for you. I'm not sure about older versions of Bash either

Comment: But the idea is not to wait is that the parent process can be killed when the timeout is reached. I will add some context to the question

Comment: Please post the waiting code in the parent. What you want to do is possible, but depends on what you do in the parent.

Comment: I added a reduced full example

Answer (score 1):

A full answer needs the code from your parent, but lacking that, here is a hint of what is probably happening:

Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 - [Section 2.11](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

> When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the
>   shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a
>   foreground command, **the trap associated with that signal shall not be
>   executed until after the foreground command has completed.**
>
> When the
>   shell is waiting, by means of the `wait` utility, for asynchronous
>   commands to complete, the reception of a signal for which a trap has
>   been set shall cause the `wait` utility to return immediately with an
>   exit status >128, immediately after which the trap associated with
>   that signal shall be taken.

*(formatting mine)*

What that means is that if your parent is waiting with anything but the `wait` command, signal handling is delayed until the end of whatever it is doing.

It's up to you to make your parent wait with `wait`, so it can receive your SIGALRM right away.

Comment: This is what I thought but even if the child (openssl) in my case, is in the background, the parent is not getting the signal

Comment: @Matteo> what it the parent doing in the meantime? The wording can be deceptive as, for instance, running `sleep 10` in the parent will prevent the signal from being received, `sleep 10` being run as a foreground command.

Comment: See my example: I am running openssl in the background

Comment: @Matteo> okay, that's what I was interested in. So normally, the `wait` command should return immediately upon receiving SIGALRM. Hmmm.

Comment: @Matteo> running your example (replacing the openssl command with a `sleep 86400`) on my system gives the expected result. I mean, trap gets executed and `wait` returns. The `sleep` command keeps running though.

Comment: I suspect that there is something strange with openssl. With other programs it works. Could it be that a child process can intercept processes of the parent?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. Now there are some edge cases of playing with terminal configuration that might cause the shell to block but I doubt highly doubt openssl messes with terminal configuration at all. Also, a child process could send the parent a `SIGSTOP`, `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOUT`, or have one sent by mistake if they live in the same process group. Still unlikely though. You may try to watch your script with `strace`.

Comment: @Matteo> actually, *if* for some reason your background command fiddles with terminal settings (say, it wants to ask for a passphrase and disables echo for that purpose), this **will** cause `SIGTTOU` to be sent to the whole process group, effectively stopping them. Again, using `strace` should show that. Or you might try to `trap` that signal and see what happens.